# How to combine multiple historic commits into one while not touching the recent ones?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-rebase, git-squash

I want to combine multiple historic commits together, while not touching the recent ones, as shown in the picture, I want to only combine the 2-4 commits together.

After reading relevant answers and posts, I have tried git `rebase - i HEAD~5` and fix and rename commits in vim, but I found this would combine them into one commit. Is there a way that I can combine the middle commits, while leaving the more recent commits untouched?

[image: git]

Comment: You must have done something wrong. The usual solution to this problem is to use `git rebase -i`. Mark commits d37d and e0f4 with "fixup" (or "squash" if you want to salvage their commit messages) instead of "pick".

Comment: @j6t You must be right. I redo it with my coworker with ```git rebase - i master``` rather than ```HEAD~5```, and that did not squash all commits into one. I was not working on master. The result will be merged into master after cleanup.

Comment: j6t is right. 'fix' is what I should have used. After that, just push force to the branch.

Answer (score 0):

@LWang,
No. You cannot combine the middle commits, while leaving the more recent commits untouched.

> However, If you have to do it, No other choice, then , you can reset to the commit you need the changes from and start committing afresh.
> I would recommend this only if there are few(one or two) commits that are to be
> preserved and you very well know what changes go into what commits.
>
> In your example, you can follow the below steps;
>
> ```
> **git reset -- mixed 66b8e0b**  (Your changes will be preserved)
> **git add <filename>**  (add only those files which are required for the middle commit)
> **git commit <commit message>** (Enter the commit message for the middle commit)
> **git add <filename>** (add all the pending files)
> **git commit -m "Wireup survey flag"**
> ```